# Catching jQuery event in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I try to catch event or error in image. I have code:

```
var image = $("#imgBrandDescription img");
var src=image.attr('src');
image.attr("src",src);
image.error(function(){
   $(this).hide();
}
```

In Google Chrome, Mozilla, IE9 everything is ok, but IE8 it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

Comment: What errors is being shown on IE8 ? any javascript errors ? looks supported in IE8 -> http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html

Comment: What is the point of these lines? `var src=image.attr('src'); image.attr("src",src);` ?

Comment: are you testing this locally?

Comment: I try to check how to upload images.If image load incorrect i need hide this image.Of course I testing locally

Comment: var src=image.attr('src'); image.attr("src",src);Don't worry about it

Comment: In Google Chrome,Mozilla,IE9 this code hide incorrect images

Answer (score 1):

FYI, From the jQuery API docs for error():

```
This event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally. Since error relies
on normal HTTP status codes, it will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file:
protocol.
```